# C# MySqlConnection: how to verify server certificate?

Tags: c#, mysql, ssl

I know how to check MySQL server certificate from command line:

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=webuser --password=mypassword --ssl-ca=ca.pem
```

But how to do it in C#, when I am creating a MySqlConnection?

Comment: Check [4.8 Tutorial: Using SSL with MySQL Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html).

Comment: Did you read the link you posted? It tells you how to establish a MySqlConnection passing a **client** certificate, it didn't tell you how to check the **server** certificate.